# Why is it recommended to insert JS through the theme, plugin, etc rather than in the post directly?

Tags: posts, javascript

Say I have a JS script that is only needed to be used in some pages. According to [this advice](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/why-does/#post-15229680) it is recommended to insert it through the theme, plugin, etc, not through the post. Why is that? Is it for security or management?

Related question: [What are the benefits of using wp_enqueue_script?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/49098/64282)

Comment: Lots of reasons. Typically JavaScript is not content, so it doesn’t belong in content according to the principle of Separation of Concerns. Also, lower privileged users are not usually allowed to post JavaScript for security reasons, so if they edited the post the script could be removed. Maintenance is another concern. Having scripts buried in content is a good way to lose track of what code is running on your site.

Comment: is the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns "Separation of concerns - Wikipedia") just another way to easy management? Is there a kind of script management system, similarly to content management system? Is WordPress one of them?

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re trying to ask.

Comment: I mean, is the purpose of that principle simply to manage the modules better?

Comment: Separation of concerns? You found an article that explains the principle in detail.

Comment: yes. I'm just trying to check my understanding. Also do you find it's easy to understand what I mean about script management system?